# How can I turn two database tables in to a multidimensional JSON file?

Tags: php, mysql, json

[image: tables in MYSQL]

The image above shows two tables in my MYSQL database; one table with facilities and another table with open hours for these facilities. Of course, in reality there are a lot more records in my database but the structure is the same.

I'd like to turn each "facility" in to a marker on a Google map. The marker should contain some info about the facility. For that, I need to create a JSON representation of my data with PHP. The JSON file will be fetched with JQUERY. The problem I've been struggling with the last couple of days is to merge the data in the two tables to a multidimensional JSON file like the one below.

How can I merge the two arrays in PHP (or the two tables in MYSQL, if that's what I'm supposed to do) to get the JSON file below?

```
    [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Facility One",
    "city": "Texas",
    "postalCode": "34928",
    "postalCity": "Texas",
    "streetAdress": "Big Street 82",
    "phone": "555-948 342",
    "website": "www.facilityone.com",
    "lat": "32.329484",
    "lng": "87.027483",
    "openHours": [{
        "weekday": "1",
        "open": "06:00:00",
        "close": "22:00:00"
    }, {
        "weekday": "2",
        "open": "06:00:00",
        "close": "22:00:00"
    }, {
        "weekday": "3",
        "open": "06:00:00",
        "close": "22:00:00"
    }, {
        "weekday": "4",
        "open": "06:00:00",
        "close": "22:00:00"
    }, {
        "weekday": "5",
        "open": "06:00:00",
        "close": "22:00:00"
    }, {
        "weekday": "6",
        "open": "08:00:00",
        "close": "20:00:00"
    }, {
        "weekday": "7",
        "open": "10:00:00",
        "close": "20:00:00"
    }]
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Facility Two",
    "city": "Chicago",
    "postalCode": "49384",
    "postalCity": "Chicago",
    "streetAdress": "Small Street 48",
    "phone": "555-329 094",
    "website": "www.facilitytwo.com",
    "lat": "59.928384",
    "lng": "95.293875",
    "openHours": [{
        "weekday": "1",
        "open": "07:30:00",
        "close": "22:00:00"
    }, {
        "weekday": "2",
        "open": "07:30:00",
        "close": "22:00:00"
    }, {
        "weekday": "3",
        "open": "07:30:00",
        "close": "22:00:00"
    }, {
        "weekday": "4",
        "open": "07:30:00",
        "close": "22:00:00"
    }, {
        "weekday": "5",
        "open": "07:30:00",
        "close": "22:00:00"
    }, {
        "weekday": "6",
        "open": "09:00:00",
        "close": "20:00:00"
    }, {
        "weekday": "7",
        "open": "10:00:00",
        "close": "18:00:00"
    }]
}]
```

Comment: You need 2 queries. first to get the facilities with an id that will  be a json. second  to retrieve the openhours. once done, you add it to your first json.

Comment: How do I add the openhours-json to the facilities-json in PHP so the final results looks like the json in my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your suggestions guys! I really appreciate them. This is the solution I went for:

```
$result1=mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);

$MainArray = array();
$Facilities = array();
$OpeningHours = array();

while ($row1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {

    $Facilities['FacilityId'] = $row1['FacilityId'];
    $Facilities['FacilityName'] = $row1['FacilityName'];
    $Facilities['FacilityCity'] = $row1['FacilityCity'];
    $Facilities['FacilityPostalCode'] = $row1['FacilityPostalCode'];
    $Facilities['FacilityPostalCity'] = $row1['FacilityPostalCity'];
    $Facilities['FacilityStreetAddress'] = $row1['FacilityStreetAddress'];
    $Facilities['FacilityPhoneNumber'] = $row1['FacilityPhoneNumber'];
    $Facilities['FacilityWebsite'] = $row1['FacilityWebsite'];
    $Facilities['lat'] = $row1['lat'];
    $Facilities['lng'] = $row1['lng'];
    $Facilities['OpeningHours'] = array();

    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM OpeningHours WHERE OpeningHoursFacility = " .$row1['FacilityId']."";
    $result2=mysqli_query($conn,$sql2);

    while ($row2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {

        $OpeningHours['OpeningHoursWeekday'] = $row2['OpeningHoursWeekday'];
        $OpeningHours['OpeningHour'] = $row2['OpeningHour'];
        $OpeningHours['ClosingHour'] = $row2['ClosingHour'];
        array_push($Facilities['OpeningHours'],$OpeningHours);
    }    

    array_push($MainArray,$Facilities);
}

$jsonData = json_encode(array('Facilities' => $MainArray), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

echo $jsonData;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should probably be done in PHP but as a fun challenge (I was bored) I thought i try to do it in pure MySQL.

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 10000000;
SELECT CONCAT('[{',
     GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(
    '"id": "',id,'",',
    '"name": "',name,'",',
    '"city": "',city,'",',
    '"postalCode": "',postalCode,'",',
    '"postalCity": "',postalCity,'",',
    '"streetAdress": "',streetAddress,'",',
    '"phone": "',phone,'",',
    '"website": "',website,'",',
    '"lat": "',lat,'",',
    '"lng": "',lng,'",',
    T.openHours
    )
    ORDER BY id ASC SEPARATOR '}, {'
   ),'}]'
  ) as JSON
FROM facilities f
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT facility,
           CONCAT('"openHours": [{',
             GROUP_CONCAT(
                CONCAT('"weekday": "',weekday,'",',
                       '"open": "',openHour,'",',
                       '"close": "',closeHour,'"'
                      )
             ORDER BY weekday asc SEPARATOR '}, {'
                         ),
                  '}]'
           ) as openHours
    FROM facility_openhours
    GROUP BY facility
    )as T 
    ON f.id = T.facility
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6dd92/11)

sqlfiddle output:
`[{"id": "1","name": "Facility One","city": "Texas","postalCode": "34928","postalCity": "Texas","streetAdress": "Big Street 82","phone": "555-948 342","website": "www.facilityone.com","lat": "32.329484","lng": "87.027483","openHours": [{"weekday": "1","open": "06:00:00","close": "22:00:00"}, {"weekday": "2","open": "06:00:00","close": "22:00:00"}, {"weekday": "3","open": "06:00:00","close": "22:00:00"}, {"weekday": "4","open": "06:00:00","close": "22:00:00"}, {"weekday": "5","open": "06:00:00","close": "22:00:00"}, {"weekday": "6","open": "08:00:00","close": "20:00:00"}, {"weekday": "7","open": "10:00:00","close": "20:00:00"}]}, {"id": "2","name": "Facility Two","city": "Chicago","postalCode": "49384","postalCity": "Chicago","streetAdress": "Small Street 48","phone": "555-329 094","website": "www.facilitytwo.com","lat": "59.928384","lng": "95.293875","openHours": [{"weekday": "1","open": "07:30:00","close": "22:00:00"}, {"weekday": "2","open": "07:30:00","close": "22:00:00"}, {"weekday": "3","open": "07:30:00","close": "22:00:00"}, {"weekday": "4","open": "07:30:00","close": "22:00:00"}, {"weekday": "5","open": "07:30:00","close": "22:00:00"}, {"weekday": "6","open": "09:00:00","close": "20:00:00"}, {"weekday": "7","open": "10:00:00","close": "18:00:00"}]}]`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have been playing around with it now but apparently I don't have the privileges to set group_concat_max_len so my JSON ends up being cut off.

I'd like to do this with PHP so if anyone could tell me how I'd be very grateful.

Comment: please see my php answer and let me know if that works for you

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible php solution.

I have a `db.php` which sets up my $conn with

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
```

then i include the db.php on all my pages.

```
<?php include 'db.php';?>
<?php 
    $sql =  "SELECT id,name,city,postalcode,postalcity,streetaddress,phone,website,lat,lng,";
    $sql .= "facility,weekday,openhour as `open`,closehour as `close` ";
    $sql .= "FROM facilities f INNER JOIN facility_openhours fo ON fo.facility = f.id ";
    $sql .= "ORDER BY f.id ASC, fo.weekday ASC";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    $facilities = array();
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $weekday = intval($row['weekday']);
            // if it's weekday 1, we set up our array
            if ($weekday == 1){
                $openHours = array();
            }
            $single_day = array("weekday" => $row['weekday'],
                                "open"    => $row['open'],
                                "close"   => $row['close']
                               );

            // add this single day to our openHours array
            array_push($openHours, $single_day);                

            if ($weekday == 7){
                $facility = array("id"   => $row['id'],
                                  "name" => $row['name'],
                                  "city" => $row['city'],
                                  "postalCode" => $row['postalcode'],
                                  "postalCity" => $row['postalcity'],
                                  "streetAddress" => $row['streetaddress'],
                                  "phone" => $row['phone'],
                                  "website" => $row['website'],
                                  "lat" => $row['lat'],
                                  "lng" => $row['lng'],
                                  "openHours" => $openHours
                                 );
                // add this facility to facilities
                array_push($facilities, $facility);
            }
        }
    }

    $my_json = json_encode($facilities);
    echo $my_json;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tin Tran!

There's some methods in your answer that I'm not familiar with. I went with another solution (see below).

Comment: Your method seems to do multiple queries...one query for each facility.
My methods just queues up open hours then whenever it reaches day 7 it adds facility since at this point all the open hours for 7 days are present.